# How to make a custom theme using Laravel and where to store theme data?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, laravel, themes

**I'm building a full website Using Laravel and this problem is facing me , I want to give the user full control to the site appearance and the ability to change website's layout without my help.**

But when I'm thinking about someway to do so by database , there are several tables with tens of columns will be added beside the colors and sections that will be added to database every time the user will change something in the layout style.

Is there any other way to store the options of the theme in XML file or anything other than database?

** Note : when I checked the database of Wordpress I hadn't found any thing concerned to themes there , So where Wordpress store theme options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your XML-like storage you can use Laravel Config. Let's say you have the file `config/templates.php`. Inside you can have a lot of stuff like.

```
return [
    'default_template' => 'layouts.templates.default',
    'posts' => 'layouts.templates.post',
    'footer' => 'layouts.includes.footer',

    'options' => [
        'full_with' => false,
        'has_footer' => true,
        'background_color' => '#fff',
        'more_keys' => 'key_value'
    ]
];
```

Then anywhere in your app you can get the default template like

```
$view = config('templates.default_template'); //will get
return view($view, compact('params'));
```

To update a key, like `has_footer`, you do

```
config(['templates.options.has_footer' => false]); //will update
```

This should get you started I think

**Simple Example**

Let's say user changes default colour from and input and submit the form. You do

```
public function updateTheme(Request $request) {
    if ( $request->has('background_colour') && $request->background_colour != '' ) {
        config(['templates.options.background_colour' => $request->background_colour]);       
    }
}
```

Comment: I think these changes should be manually changes , So how can I change themes and all their options from Dashboard ?

Comment: I litteraly showed you how to do that but you didnt read. my last line of code shows how to change that from Dashboard.

Comment: Oh yes got it , but please have some patient because it is very important to me . I can change config keys like you said , but I have another question >> Where do you store value false you gave to "has_footer"?

For example: I have form to change settings , so If I write the last line you said , the key value will change permanently in the config file ?

Comment: You store them in the file `config/templates.php`. If this helps with your question, please mark my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: a small problem : it just store data in array for a while but when I call it in another page the default data came back.